# VAST Documentation

Tags: vast

I've done a fair amount of research for VAST compliance. There isn't much out there other then the stuff on the IAB website. (Please link me to content if you have other sources of media on the subject). There isn't exactly specific instructions about certain things.. here is my question:

http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast2VPAIDLinear.xml

On the second Creative there is an HTML resource, a Companion with the dimensions 250x300.

How do I know where to place this iframe / banner ?

After this question is answered, I have some more.

Maybe a link to a working player? videojs.vpaid isn't working with this.

Answer (score 0):

***Basic rule:*** **If there is no rule, create a default rule and provide options for everything else.**

Regarding your example VAST we can find something in the documentation:

> If the intention is to show different non-linears at different points in the playback then multiple Creatives should be used.

Potential options could be:

- 0 (default): show one of them (best matching)
- 1: show ALL of them (if possible & matches)
- 2: show NON of them (conflict)

Regarding matching:

- minSuggestedDuration
- height & width
- apiFramework
- ...

For CompanionAds it should be clear: Either you have slots to show them, or not.

Comment: So, for companionads there are supposed to be slots over the video player that load ads... what about *all* of the possible situations, where can i find details about this ?

Comment: Please specify **all** possible situations! You can't find details about everything as there are Functional Requirements and Non-Functional Requirements. A spec will not tell you, what your customer actually want to archive.

Comment: Hi zyexal: I've made some progress working with VAST, here is another question I have:: how do I know how many Creatives to parse for ?? How do I know if its a staticresource or im looking for or an htmlresource?? what do I do with trackingevents?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but you will find all informations you need within the [Specs 2](http://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/VAST-2_0-FINAL.pdf) / [Specs 3](https://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/VASTv3_0.pdf) / [Specs 4](http://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/VAST4.0_Updated_April_2016.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use [this](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector) tool to troubleshoot or validate VAST xml (event firing, MediaFile, etc.). you can easily toggle between HTML5 & Flash Players.